# Rails UJS: How to evaluate Javascript response on HTTP error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I notice that when I do AJAX submission using Rails UJS form, the Javascript response will only be evaluated when the server return HTTP success (2xx) and do nothing if the server return status code 4xx or 5xx.

I want to modify this behavior so that Javascript response will be evaluated even if the server return HTTP error. I'm thinking about binding my form with the event `ajax:error`, but then I have to do this for every AJAX form I have within my application. Anyone has an idea how to do this globally?

One more question: can I check if the content type returned by server is Javascript via JQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all Rails UJS handlers need to have data-remote="true" defined, you could bind to the ajax:error event globally by doing

```
$('[data-remote="true"]').on('ajax:error', my_special_error_callback);
```

Then you need to ensure that you define your callback to check on the error codes:

```
function my_special_error_callback(event, data, status, xhr) {
    if(status == 'error') {
    alert('error');
    responseText =  JSON.parse(data.responseText)["errors"] // This is dependent on how you're returning your errors from Rails
}
```